# Vagrant box doesn't start (Connection timeout)

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I try to start my vagrant box on my Windows 8.1 (64 bit) system but it doesn't work. I'm using this setup on two mashines without problems.

This is what I get:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: vagrant-lamp_default_1411285570202_20465
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 => 8080 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

I already looked for solutions but nothing helped. I've virtualization enabled and tried to run the mashine in the GUI mode, but no way... Anyone an idea? More information needed? Please ask, I don't know what I should provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by disabling Hyper-V since Virtual Box cannot run with Hyper-V enabled. You have to decide what do you want to use.

Disabling Hyper-V: Search for "Windows Features". There you can uncheck Hyper-V. After that you have to restart your machine.

*I rather suggest to use a Vagrant box which provides Hyper-V.*

Comment: do you mind telling where you disabled Hyper-V, please improve your answer

Comment: I adjusted my answer.